# how to generate an automatic id(incremental) in android?

Tags: android, sqlite, auto-increment

i have one orderid field in android form .. now i want to add a number along with the content of orderid such that each time the number should be in incremental manner..

for example
if user input 123 in orderid then i want to store 123100 in database
similarly on next run i want to store 123101 in database ..and so on...how will i do this

plz help

Comment: Well you have the _id parameter in your db which acts as a unique primary key everytime. Essentially u need to add (order_id*1000+_id+99)

Comment: The constraint is autoincrement but as Viktor states, if the name of the column is _id and is an integer and primary key, it will automatically autoincrement. From the sqlite docs, commonly asked questions faq: http://www.sqlite.org/faq.html#q1

Comment: Sir, What i need to do to access _id field? can i direcly use _id in program as you have mentioned or do i need to define _id before? if i need to define _id then please show me the way to do it?

Comment: Sir , I want like every time this user interface comes ..orderid element of user interface should already have value ..which is 1 more then the previous value..and rest input i am taking from user..plz help

Comment: what if i want an id of type ame101..ame102 ..so on

Answer (score 5):

Create a field with `INTEGER PRIMARY KEY` as a type with the name `_id`. This field will increase by one each time a value is added into the database.